# Wordcloud on dataframe in R

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

Being new to R, I am lacking a few basics. Is it possible to make a wordcloud on a dataframe?
my data is like:

```
X  x
a  10
b  8
c  6
d  4
```

Can i make a workcloud on the above data where X is the word and x is its frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Just specify 
`wordcloud(words = data$X, freq = data$x)`

Be aware that by default the minimum frequency is set to 3. You might want to adjust this. just check the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Just try for a sample 
    abc<-data.frame(X=LETTERS[1:26],x=sample(1:26))
    wordcloud(abc$X,abc$x,scale = c(5,.5),min.freq = 2,colors = brewer.pal(10,"Paired"))
```

[image]